# Java circle intersection - central section

Tags: java, android, geometry

I'm trying to get the coordinates of the arcs (denoted in blue) (so that I can visually draw them [in Android path.drawArc()]) of any 2 (and eventually $n$) circles for the 'central' portion (denoted in red).

[image: here's a representation]

I have found [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html), but unfortunately I'm not at all mathematically minded!

I have coded something to find the intersection points... If that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no `path.drawArc()`, only [`Canvas.drawArc`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29), [`Path.addArc`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#addArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float%29) and [`Path.arcTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#arcTo%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float%29). All of these need a `RectF oval` argument which I would *guess* describes the size and position of the circle. So if you want to draw the right boundary of the lens-shaped area, this belongs to the boundary of the left circle, so you'd set `oval`  to the bounding box of the left circle. Then you need two angles, `startAngle` and `sweepAngle`. You can get them from [`Math.atan2(y, x)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29), where `(x, y)` is the vector which points from the center of the circle to one of the points of intersection. So knowing the points of intersection will be very useful. You'd use one to compute the start angle and the other the end angle of the first arc. The sweep angle is simply the difference between end and start. For the second arc, reverse the roles of start and end and you'll obtain an essentially closed path, although you might have to issue an explicit [`close`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#close%28%29) call to make that closing explicit.

An alternative approach would be using [`Path.op(circle1, circle2, Path.Op.INTERSECT)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#op%28android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Path.Op%29). `circle1` and `circle2` could be formed by [`Path.addCircle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#addCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Path.Direction%29). This approach would delegate the whole intersection math to the Framework, but it does require a recent API (namely API level 19), so it will not work on older devices.

All of the above is untested, from reading the reference and knowing how similar frameworks behave.

Comment: Brilliant! Working perfectly (well nearly, there's a weird -87 needed in this code) `public float getAngle(PointF oOrigin, PointF oTarget)
 {
     float fAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(oTarget.x - oOrigin.x, oTarget.y - oOrigin.y));

     if(fAngle < 0){
      fAngle += 360;
     }
     
     return fAngle-87; // -87 to adjust for Android coordinate system (?)
 }`

Comment: @user3398063: I guess that's more like a `90` instead of `87`, and I guess it's due to the fact that you computed `atan2(x,y)` instead of `atan2(y,x)` as indicated in my answer.